# comma error while importing csv using appscript to google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, import-csv

I am trying to import a csv file to google sheets via google appscript. everything works well except in the last few rows the data is being copied after skipping a row and also it keeps adding more commas to the those empty rows. not sure why. i Have added a test file for reference
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jnzPalCAgO84kxUBrM-aIobIDHu7c99VStJySEyUkKo/edit?usp=sharing

```
function getCSVAndAppend(spreadsheetId, folderId, filename) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1TMFXWDTJpwqTY0JsCefuAean4n9fWIIh');
  var files = folder.getFilesByName('Dealers joined data.csv');
  var openSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1E5z7Qd3KRb5geNKlQiYhliYCOtJ0A8ICmZFcUcA1-lI');
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var header = csvData.shift();
    var lastrow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
    activeSheet.getRange(lastrow + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would look very closely at that file.  I would suspect that the file is corrupted somewhere near the end.  Yes I see embedded commas in your test file near the end.  Remove them

Comment: There's also several lines with extra white space characters.   I'd probably use regex to eliminate all unwanted characters from every cell.